# Are there consumer-level game play analysis systems that overlay the analysis on the board real-time?

Tags: analysis, software

An example of what I mean would be [Thinking Table](http://mw2mw.com/thinking-table), though the Thinking Table is not a consumer product:

> Thinking Table is a series of works that explore the invisible, elusive nature of
>   thought. Play chess against a transparent intelligence, its evolving
>   thought process visible on the board before you.

[image]

**CAPTION:** The above image is three images, from left to right, the images are of the opening, middle, and end of the same game. The lines shown on the board are the engine's "thoughts" for one move during the game.

> Each Thinking Machine is an artificial intelligence program – ready,
>   willing and able to play chess with the viewer. If the viewer
>   confronts the program, the computer’s thought process is sketched on
>   screen as it plays. A map is created from the traces of literally
>   thousands of possible futures as the program tries to decide its best
>   move. Those traces become a key to the invisible lines of force in the
>   game as well as a window into the spirit of a thinking machine. The
>   pace of interaction is deliberative, unlike the rushed tempo of
>   popular video games. Indeed the true subject of the piece is not games
>   or chess, but contemplation and introspection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Fritz has something like this, not to the extent of going as deep as the images you provided, but any potential patterns that it likes are represented graphically, using coloured arrows and squares, while analysing.

---

**Example of Fritz visual output:**
[image]

**SOURCE:** [Visualize search in Fritz 10](http://www.chessbase.com/newsdetail.asp?newsid=3863) (21.05.2007)

Comment: "Pretty sure"... :-) ...made me smile. So, based on the hint that it might, I just did a quick super Google, and found [proof that Fritz has Visualize search](http://www.chessbase.com/newsdetail.asp?newsid=3863). Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 2):

Chess Tiger Pro (for iOS).
[Link to App Store](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/chess-tiger-pro/id423198259)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Thinking Machine 6](http://www.bewitched.com/chess/) is an online JavaScript port of previous Thinking machines (I remember seeing [Thinking Machine 4](http://turbulence.org/spotlight/thinking/) over a decade ago and it dates back to 2004). The source code is publicly available by looking at the page's source js file.

[image: Thinking Machine 6 thinking]

Also, since Stockfish shows its top results while searching, it should be possible to build a UCI-compliant frontend to visualize all the currently searching top lines. Actually, Lichess's analysis board does show Stockfish's current best moves in real-time.

[image: Stockfish thinking]